# Making Ajax call from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery ajax call and it works fine in a purely jquery file.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "kscript.jsp",
    type: "POST",
    data: {st:start, sp:stop},
    dataType: "html"
});
request.done(function(msg) {
    $("#output").html( msg );
    alert("Success!!!"+msg);
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Thereafter I rewrote my code as a javascript, but I am now putting the ajax call directly inside a javascript function.  This hasn't worked and I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

```
function myAjax(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "kscript.jsp",
        type: "POST",
        data: {st:start, sp:stop},
        dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#output").html( msg );
        alert("Success!!!"+msg);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
xmlhttp.open("POST","kscript.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("st=start&sp=stop");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

}
```

but the same error: 500 Internal Server Error.  In all these instances, the error is pointing to kscript.jsp .I have ensured that the URL and spelling is correct but hasn't worked.  I would appreciate your suggestion to fix this problem.

here is kscript.jsp

```
    <%

        String astart = request.getParameter("start");
        String sptimes=request.getParameter("stop");

        out.print("<h1> Start is: "+start+"    --  Stop is"+stop +"</h1>");

    %>
```

Comment: How are you using the function `myAjax()`?

Comment: I made a simple call to myAjax from another javascript function.  Like this myAjax();

Comment: could you post kscript.jsp file ?

Comment: If you are getting `500 Internal Server Error` then it is a server problem, obviously the ajax is "working" if you get a `500` back. Check your server logs for errors.

Comment: Your problem is not related to the javascript change.

Comment: Your parameters are `st` and `sp`, not `start` and `stop`.

Answer (score 0):

it's looks like a folders structure problem, you shoudl ensure that the relative path is fine, I mean, if you are calling from a js you should point to /jsp/yourJsp.jsp , checkit... by the way, are you using the F12 tools to validate the response from the server ?

Comment: I sure did.  The file is in the same folder as when I wrote this completely as jquery and everything works fine.  I haven't changed the location of the jsp files. It's kind a wierd.  And yes, I also used F12 on IE to get the console.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are making some mistake to call java script method.so check or have you describe ajaxcall inside javascript tag.

Comment: I simply called the function containing the Ajax call using ajaxFunction();

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the wrong parameters in jsp.

The error occurs here:

```
String astart = request.getParameter("start");
```

the parameters are `st` and `sp`, not `start` and `stop`.

you need:

```
String astart = request.getParameter("st");
String sptimes=request.getParameter("sp");
```

Or, you can change the js to pass the correct parameters:

```
data: {start:start, stop:stop},
```

Comment: Yes that's true.  I actually did that in my code. I copied just a snippet from the code and changed those parameters around.  It  hasn't worked tho'.

Comment: @bdfios keep debugging the jsp, 500 error means an error happened on the server, not the client.

Comment: Ok.  I will.  Thanks everyone for helping.